# RPi 4B Ubuntu 19.10 Resolution problem

Tags: display-resolution

I just got a Raspberry Pi 4 model B with 4 GB of Ram. I installed ubuntu 19.10 server for RPi and xubuntu-desktop. The problem is that I have it connected with a 4K TV and the resolution is 1892x984 and it cannot change. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

After installing Ubuntu 19.10, I had a similar problem connecting the Raspberry Pi 4 model to a 4k computer monitor. Adding the following lines to `/boot/firmware/usercfg.txt` solved it for me:

```
disable_overscan=1
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_enable_4kp60=1
```

If this doesn't help, there is a lot of information on the Raspberry Pi github site, e.g. you can find information about video options at https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/blob/master/configuration/config-txt/video.md

Answer (score 0):

You need to add  `disable_overscan=1` in the file `/boot/firmware/usercfg.txt`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately it doesn't work. I also tried to change the overscan but if I change the value to something different than the default value it garbles the image. When I change the resolution to 4k (hdmi_enable_4kp60=1, hdmi_group=1, hdmi_mode=97) I don't have a problem with overscan but there is a problem with playing youtube and netflix. There is a lot of lag. So I want to try in full HD 1080p but I cannot fix the overscan. Any ideas?