# Screen Resolution low on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: 20.04, display-resolution, raspberrypi

The only choice I have for screen resolution is 1824 X 984 (9:5)
I know that my monitor will do 1920 X 1080 (16:9)

I installed Ubuntu Server 20.04 and then installed the Ubuntu desktop.
should we not have more choices for our monitor resolution?
Raspberry Pi 4 8 GB.

Answer (score 1):

I have Ubuntu 20.04 64bit rpi4 8Gb, ubuntu dektop,
2 24" monitor in simple HD
this is my /boot/firmware/usercfg.txt:

```
dtparam=spi=off
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
hdmi_drive:0=1
hdmi_group:0=2
hdmi_mode:0=82
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_drive:1=1
hdmi_group:1=2
hdmi_mode:1=82
```

the :0 and :1 are ti address monitor.

after this the monitor are detected well
The networkManager and wifi make me crazy but this is a different story.

Answer (score 0):

I had this simular problem aswell and I found a post for 19.04 on rpi here([https://askubuntu.com/questions/1202090/rpi-4b-ubuntu-19-10-resolution-problem][1]). you need to modify the file /boot/firmware/usercfg.txt and add the following lines:

```
disable_overscan=1
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_enable_4kp60=1
```

hope this helps and good luck.